# NancyFx Response.ReasonPhrase is being overridden on XHR requests

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest, nancy

In the following code (below), the ReasonPhrase seems to be ignored and defaulted to "Not Found" on XHR requests and for some reason works for non-XHR requests.

```
        pipelines.OnError += (ctx, ex) =>
        {
            var response = ex is NotFoundException ? new Response
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
                ReasonPhrase = ex.Message
            }
            : new Response
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                ReasonPhrase = "An unexpected error has occurred."
            };

            return response;
        };
```

[image: XHR example]
[image: non-XHR example]

(Yes I had to blank out some stuff but please trust me, nothing else is different - the only diff is just XHR or not XHR).

I've also set a breakpoint where the response is returned. It is in fact returning the correct response with the correct ReasonPhrase each time (for XHR and non-XHR requests) however XHR requests always just return a ReasonPhrase of "Not Found" back to the client (according to Google Chrome's Developer Tools and Advanced Rest Client Chrome app).

Comment: Have you been able to figure this one out ?

Comment: Nope, gave up on it long ago :(

Comment: Ahah! Same here, passed the message in the response content instead - but the good thing is that it actually also feels like the proper way to do it from a protocol standpoint